# Rails Active Record Callbacks error in nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble with Active Record callbacks in a model which contains `accepts_nested_attributes`

I call `build_associated_parties`using an `after_create` callback, but these values are not being saved and I get `<nil>` errors. I've also tried using `before_create` & `after_initialize` callbacks without success.

What is causing the callbacks to fail?

connection.rb

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :reason, :established, :connector, :connectee1,
                  :connectee2, :connectee1_attributes,
                  :connectee2_attributes, :connector_attributes 

  belongs_to :connector, class_name: "User" 
  belongs_to :connectee1, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :connectee2, class_name: "User"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :connector, :connectee1, :connectee2 

  belongs_to :permission 

  after_create :build_associated_parties    

  # builds connectee's, connector, permission objects
  def build_associated_parties   
    build_connector
    build_connectee1
    build_connectee2
    build_permission
  end
```

connection_controller.rb

```
class ConnectionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @connection = Connection.new
  end

  def create        
    @connection = Connection.new params[:connection]
    if @connection.save     
      flash[:notice] = "Connection created successfully!"
      redirect_to @connection
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

However, if I instead build these attributes inside the controller as shown below, I don't get the error. This is nice, but it seems to go against keeping business logic code out of the controller.

```
class ConnectionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @connection = Connection.new
    @connection.build_connectee1
    @connection.build_connectee2
    @connection.build_connector
  end
end
```

How can I accomplish the same functionality with code in the model? Are there advantages to keeping it in the model?

Answer (score 1):

You called your method `build_associated_parties` after `connection` is created, so how these methods:

```
 build_connector
 build_connectee1
 build_connectee2
 build_permission
```

know what params it will use? So they don't know what values are passed into method then they will get error. In controller, they didn't have error because they used values of `params[:connection]`.

On your form, if you already have fields for `connector, connectee1, connectee2`, you should put code which initialize object in your new controller. When you save `@connection`, it's saved those object too. I think these codes aren't need to put into model. Your model only should put other logic code, like search or calculation...

Comment: You're saying I should leave the `build` methods inside my controller? How do I then also create (or build) a new permission object which is not inside my Connection Controller? Permission is inside a Controller of it's own.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand what you are doing. You want to call `methods` to build new associated object in model, what is it for?

Comment: I want to do 2 things when I create a new object of Connection class. 1) I want to build the nested attribute objects (`Connector, Connectee1, Connectee2`). 2) I want to build a new object of Permission class. Using the solution with code for each nested attribute, such as `@connection.build_connector`, inside my Connection controller solves #1, but not #2. That is because I can't  make a call to Controller (Permission) from inside another Controller (Connection).

Comment: I think #2, you can use `render template` from action inside Connection controller to an action of Permission controller.

Comment: Your answer did work for #1, but #2. Ultimately, I ended up moving methods from controller to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Moved logic out of controller and back into model. However, the `build_*` code was overwriting the values I was passing into the nested attributes.

By adding **unless {attribute}** to these `build_` methods, I was able to properly pass in the values.

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :reason, :established, :connector, :connectee1, :connectee2,
                :connectee1_attributes, :connectee2_attributes, :connector_attributes

```
  belongs_to :connector, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :connectee1, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :connectee2, class_name: "User"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :connector, :connectee1, :connectee2

  belongs_to :permission

  after_initialize :build_associated_parties

  validates :reason, :presence => true
  validates_length_of :reason, :maximum => 160

  #builds connectee's, connector, permission objects
  def build_associated_parties
    build_connector unless connector
    build_connectee1 unless connectee1
    build_connectee2 unless connectee2
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

`after_create` is a big no. Use `after_initialize` in your model and use `self` inside your `build_associated_parties` method. See if that works.

Comment: `self` method didn't correct the issue, tried using `after_create` and `after_initialize`